# Load xml from javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, xmlhttprequest

Totally new to XML and I've been struggling on this very simple objective for too long (though I can find enough on the internet about it). Just need the values out of this xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<materials>
    <basic>
        <uurloon>10</uurloon>
        <setloon>100</setloon>
    </basic>
    <extra>
        <geluid>150</geluid>
        <ledset>35</ledset>
        <strobo>20</strobo>
        <laser>50</laser>
    </extra>
</materials>
```

In javascript, I use this code to get the xml data:

```
// load xml file
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
   xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {    // IE 5/6
   xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xhttp.open("GET", "pricing.xml", false);
xhttp.send();
xmlDoc = xhttp.responseXML; 

var uurloon = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("uurloon")[0].childNodes[0].text;
var setloon = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("setloon")[0].childNodes[0].text
alert('end');
```

No result though, cause I'm not seeing the alert..

Comment: Are you limited to javascript? or do you have php as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your server isn't returning the appropriate `Content-Type` header. The `responseXML` property only works if the server returns a `Content-Type: text/xml` or similar `+xml` header.

[See Ajax Patterns](http://ajaxpatterns.org/XMLHttpRequest_Call#XML_Responses):

> The service just needs to output an XML Content-type header...

[From the w3c](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#document-response-entity-body):

> If final MIME type is not null, text/xml, application/xml, and does not end in +xml [...] return null.

If you have no access to the server and can't change the `Content-Type` header, use the `overrideMimeType` function to force the `XMLHttpRequest` to treat the response as `text/xml`:

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
   xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {    // IE 5/6
   xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xhttp.overrideMimeType('text/xml');

xhttp.open("GET", "pricing.xml", false);
xhttp.send(null);
xmlDoc = xhttp.responseXML;

var uurloon = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("uurloon")[0].childNodes[0].text;
var setloon = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("setloon")[0].childNodes[0].text
alert('end');
```

citation: http://blog-rat.blogspot.com/2010/11/xmlhttprequestresponsexml-returns-null.html

Answer (score 2):

```
// load xml file
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
   xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {    // IE 5/6
   xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xhttp.open("GET", "pricing.xml", false);
xhttp.send(null);
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
 if (xhttp.status == "200")
xmlDoc = xhttp.responseXML; 
}
var uurloon = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("uurloon")[0].childNodes[0].textContent;
var setloon = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("setloon")[0].childNodes[0].textContent;
alert('end');
```

Answer (score 0):

I make a simple test with a file called price.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<materials>
    <basic>
        <uurloon>10</uurloon>
        <setloon>100</setloon>
    </basic>
    <extra>
        <geluid>150</geluid>
        <ledset>35</ledset>
        <strobo>20</strobo>
        <laser>50</laser>
    </extra>
</materials>
```

And html with this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="es">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title></title>
</head> 
<body onload="init()">
<p>Hola</p>
<script>
function init(){
    // load xml file
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
       xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {    // IE 5/6
       xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xhttp.open("GET", "price.xml", false);
    xhttp.send();
    xmlDoc = xhttp.responseXML; 

    var uurloon = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("uurloon")[0].childNodes[0].textContent;
    var setloon = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("setloon")[0].childNodes[0].textContent;
    console.log(uurloon,setloon); //give me "10 100"
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And in works for me. I think fails for you because you are calling the `.text` atribute instead `.textContent`.